# Different pronunciations for different parts of speech

Tags: pronunciation

I read http://www.dailywritingtips.com/careful-with-words-used-as-noun-and-verb/ and http://www.businessenglishresources.com/31-2/teachers-section/mini-lessons/pronunciation-lessons-pronunciation-changes-in-words-that-are-both-nouns-and-verbs/

1. How do you pronounce the noun [correlate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/correlate)? How do you determine this?  Is it like the noun [isolate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/isolate)?
2. What's this phenomenon called? Are there any general lessons to be learned here? Is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun?
3. Are there any exceptions?

Comment: As to the "how" the link you consulted gives the sound and IPA transcription. As for the rest of the question -ate is one of the tricky suffixes. For a start could  this two pages from pronuncian.com be of help? [1](http://www.pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=48) [2](http://pronuncian.com/Podcast/Default.aspx?Episode=177&Language)

Answer (score 2):

> How do you pronounce the noun correlate? How do you determine this? Is it like the noun isolate?

Yes, there's an entire family of words like this: *increase*, *record*, *rebel*, *survey*, and so on.

Generally speaking, when you have a word that can be both a verb and a noun and it's polysyllabic, it tends to have an unstressed final syllable in the noun form, and tends to have a stressed final syllable in the verb form. So the verbs would be

- "re · **cord**", "re · **bel**", "sur · **vey**", and so on,

while the nouns would be

- "**re** · cord", "**re** · bel", "**sur** · vey", and so on.

> What's this phenomenon called? Are there any general lessons to be learned here? Is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun?

That's the one!

> Are there any exceptions?

English is, as you probably know, rife with exceptions to every rule. For example, these would be pronounced identically:

> That book is a great **read**.
>
> She **reads** the book.